# How do I tell Sinatra what environment (development, test, production) it is?

Tags: ruby, heroku, rubygems, sinatra

(Disclaimer: New to deploying Sinatra on Heroku.)

I have seen http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html and it tells me to `set :environment, :production`. My question is, how can I specify it to do: "when in Heroku, set environment as production, else stay in test/development."

Also, even after putting the line `set :environment, :production`, I don't think it is working because when I try to `rackup` the app locally, it's still running (when I know (or I think I know) that it shouldn't because I haven't installed postgres on my computer).

Gemfile

```
group :production do
  gem 'dm-postgres-adapter'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'dm-sqlite-adapter', "~> 1.2.0"
end
```

Comment: "when in Heroku, set environment as production, else stay in test/development." [It does this automatically anyway](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#rack-applications), no need to specify the environment yourself. Just remove the statement. I'd suggest that you *do* install postgres locally, you don't gain anything by using SQLite locally.

Answer (score 18):

The Sinatra environment has nothing to do with the gems inside the production group being loaded. These are separate and don't work with each other.

Sinatra takes the environment from the `RACK_ENV` environment variable, just start it with `RACK_ENV=production rackup`

Bundler works a bit different, you can choose which groups it should exclude when running bundle install: `bundle install --without production`

Answer (score 5):

Sinatra uses the `APP_ENV` environment variable. You can also set it explicitly via settings, as you mentioned.

> A symbol specifying the deployment environment; typically set to one of :development, :test, or :production. The :environment defaults to the value of the APP_ENV environment variable (ENV['APP_ENV']), or :development when no APP_ENV environment variable is set.

That is how you tell Sinatra the environment.