# Ruby Sinatra configured to work on production and development

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I've created the application on Sinatra, which represents a simple API. I want to make deployment on production and development. I want to choose during deployment, whether it should be dev or production, and the logic of some methods should change, depending on deployment type. 
Is there any idea, how it can be done and some example of solving this issue.

Example:
I have code

```
get '/api/test' do
  return "It is dev"
end
```

but after deployment to production I would like see after run /api/test

```
It is PROD
```

How it can be done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I tell Sinatra what environment (development, test, production) it is?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19420321/how-do-i-tell-sinatra-what-environment-development-test-production-it-is)

Comment: @AmauryMedeiros I updated my question, I don't understand how to work it. Please explain me.

Comment: The nominated duplicate is pretty useless, and not _quite_ a duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Sinatra Documentation](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Environments):

> Environments can be set through the RACK_ENV environment variable. The
>   default value is "development". In the "development" environment all
>   templates are reloaded between requests, and special not_found and
>   error handlers display stack traces in your browser. In the
>   "production" and "test" environments, templates are cached by default.
>
> To run different environments, set the RACK_ENV environment variable:
>
> RACK_ENV=production ruby my_app.rb

You also can use the `development?` and `production?` methods to change the logic:

```
get '/api/test' do
  if settings.development?
    return "It is dev"
  else if settings.production?
    return "It is PROD"
  end
end
```

If `settings.development?` doesn't work, you can try `Sinatra::Application.environment == :development`

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
get '/api/test' do
  if settings.development?
    return "It is dev"
  else
    return "Not dev"
  end
end
```

[Official guide -> environments](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Environments)

Comment: i think

    `ruby myapp.rb -E production`

or [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832060/sinatra-configuring-environments-on-the-fly#5834009)